# Should we try to create Storybuilding.SE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Worldbuilding.SE legend has it that the idea of Storybuilding.SE was once discussed, but at the time the rules of Stack Exchange were so rigid that such a Stack could never succeed or even graduate from [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Time has passed. It's been proven that people completely ignore rules and that few people are really interested in enforcing them. Further, Stack Exchange appears to be relaxing its belief that every answer should have the immutable objectivity of solving a mathematics problem. Indeed, since Stack Exchange seems to care very little if we're following any of its rules at all (interventions in the last 5 years have been so rare that I can remember only one), there may be some wiggle room.

And if this Stack has proven anything at all, it's that people have as much fun (or, frankly, even more fun) answering storybuilding questions than they do worldbuilding questions.

**Question:** Is it time to try and create Storybuilding.SE over at Area 51?

> ***NOTE:*** Do *NOT* run over to Area 51 and create Storybuilding.SE. It's a LOT more complicated than that! We'll be required to establish the rules of behavior for that Stack and that deserves more thought than just ringing the proverbial bell. A minimum number of interested participants are required, and if we don't see a lot of support here, it's a waste of time (might even be a negative, setting a precedent) to try to create the Stack. On the other hand, it would be helpful for people interested in this process to visit Area 51 and familiarize themselves with how that service works. And remember, the only people who decide if a Stack graduates Area 51 is Stack Exchange staff.

Issues:

- Storybuilding.SE (SB.SE) will be stuck with the same Help Center problems that Worldbuilding (WB.SE) suffers and then some. This means that Storybuilding.SE's creation must include, from the outset, *policy-based rule overrides.* [SE allows communities to override rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385244/395595), but they don't like it and want to see it minimized.
- If SB.SE were created today, there would be an enormous blur between SB.SE and WB.SE. That's a very real problem as it would be best if the two sites conscientiously migrated questions to the appropriate Stack. I wouldn't be surprised if our Stack Exchange Overlords expected us to clearly differentiate between the two Stacks.
- Stack Exchange does not want to be perceived as another Reddit or Quora. That means establishing real and practical rules for *excluding* questions. If the Area 51 participants can't explain what questions are off-topic, SB.SE will likely not be allowed to graduate Area 51.
- There is no guarantee that Stack Exchange will allow SB.SE to graduate Area 51. It would be the most subjective Stack they have. It might be the most subjective Stack they ever have.

*Finally, it's worth noting that an astute observer might ask, "why don't we just broaden ourselves here at WB.SE so we can answer story-based questions?" There's still a LOT of resistance to story-based questions here. Therefore, I don't believe it's worth even trying to open the doors to storybuilding questions on this Stack. Besides, I can see a clear difference between the question goals, so I believe there's value to having two sites.*

Comment: Problem which needs to be solved beforehand : What definition of storybuilding are we using here? I know by your stated closure reasons your definition is quite broader than mine.

Comment: @Tortliena That's actually part of the Area 51 process: defining what everything means. The purpose of this post is to test whether or not there's enough interest to even try. There would be a couple of follow-ups about the bigger, more encompassing things (like the definition of "storybuilding") so we're all on the same page. If everything's a thumbs up at that point, then we invoke Area 51 and start the process. Please note that one of the major reasons for Area 51 is to let people hash out the details before it becomes a real Stack. We won't do all that here.

Comment: But, to provide a general idea: Questions closed here as "too story-based" would be answered there. That, of course, assumes that whatever rules are established for SB.SE don't exclude a particular question.

Comment: what is story-building?

Comment: @LeeMcGee Think of it this way. Worldbuilding is the creation and consistent use of rules governing a world wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. An example would be "what would happen if my character, born on Earth, tried to jump on a world with 1.5G gravity?" Storybuilding is the development of plot, circumstances, and character traits and decisions. An example would be "what would motivate my character, born on Earth, to jump in 1.5G gravity?" The difference doesn't sound like much, but the first Q has an objective answer, the second Q pretty much doesn't.

Comment: @JBH thanks! I haven't looked much at writing.se, I assume such questions are off topic there too?

Comment: @LeeMcGee They are. If I recall, [writing.se] came online shortly after [worldbuilding.se] and had the same basic problems with Stack Exchange's objective-based structure as we do. Consequently, [writing.se] is 100% about how to write, not at all what to write.

Comment: @LeeMcGee Writing.SE is about the process of writing. Techniques for how to write dialogue, how to present a scene without skipping relevant details or overloading it with irrelevant ones. Also more about the business of writing - how or when you might self-publish. That sort of thing. Questions aren't "write this story for me".

Comment: /It's been proven that people completely ignore rules...
NOTE: Do NOT run over to Area 51 and create Storybuilding.SE/   now I am compelled to run over to area 51...  must ... resist...

Comment: @Willk I'm actually a bit surprised that it hasn't happened yet, people being the way they are. Planning as a group is rarely humanity's forte.

Comment: **QUIBBLE**: SB.SE would be, perhaps, the *second most subjective forum*. WB is the most subjective because we deal with so many irrealia. SB would be much more objective because the craft of writing does have certain rules, practices, guidelines, and other bits and bobs that make it much easier to come up with objective answers.

Comment: ***I'm actually a bit surprised that it hasn't happened yet, people being the way they are*** --- I think it's just easier to try and sneak a storybuilding query in here. Depending on who's awake at the time and how good the question is, it might be answered and upvoted before the proverbial closure brigade can muster its forces!

Comment: 76 views and, in comparison, almost no votes or contributions. Are there so many bots scraping SE that nobody's actually using Meta?

Comment: It’s been discussed before and rejected http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77143/storytelling-and-blot-buidling/77146#77146

Comment: @sphennings At a guess, that was almost 10 years ago. A lot has changed. Indeed, we don't allow any question or answer from that far back to set a precedent for judging the viability of questions and answers today. Worse, what's a "blot?"

Answer (score 5):

## No

The SB.SE as described will be just creative writing prompts. While people can have fun with that*, I do not think it has value for the SE network.

I do not think SE has to house *everything*. It can leave topics for other sites.

---

*I certainly personally do like them.

Comment: That's the problem we're having, though, right? We all like them, despite they're being entirely off-topic here. Sometimes they're closed, sometimes not. When they are, it's usually after a dozen answers are posted. *The feature seems to already exist on the black market.* So, if we discard the value-to-SE issue (which may or may not be true, how much value does [worldbuilding.se] bring to SE? At least 90% of the answers are so specific to one person's world that they're rarely valuable to the next person). Ignoring SE, is there a reason why we wouldn't want to pitch the idea?

Comment: I'm just going for the "no" based on my view that these do not belong on the network. And yes, I do realise they are already posted here. That's beyond my control. Do note, that I am also powerless from stopping anybody from pitching the idea to SE. Who knows, maybe they do like it and do make SB.SE. I really do not have any authority there, nor really wish to interfere. Only sharing what I think here.

Comment: That's the goal, @VLAZ, to get opinions. I'm playing devil's adocate everywhere to make sure the issue is as hashed out as it can be. Thanks for contibuting.

Comment: Not sure how proposing an alternative site will do anything to change or clarify policy here.

Comment: The argument in favor would be that if another such site existed within SE then storybuilding questions can simply be migrated rather than closed, which is a far friendlier action in general. (This will invite arguments and fingerpointing over what belongs where, but we already do that.)

Comment: @JamieB You cannot have a writings prompt site within the SE model. That’s ok. Writing prompts are great and there are great sites focused on them. However SE is not designed to support such activity.

Comment: @sphennings Workplace SE is almost nothing but subjective questions with anecdotal answers. SciFi consists largely of people's half remembered stories and various attempts at guessing what they are. There's even a coding SE that's literally just challenges and various ways to implement it, purely for fun, in coding languages that are utterly impractical. I'm not too convinced about the limits of SE.

Answer (score 4):

## NO

I can foresee that a StoryBuilding SE could have issues with accusations of plagiarism.  How could members of such a site avoid being asked to review/write/plot students' homework questions?  It would be all very well to say in the help pages that homework questions shouldn't be asked, but how can we tell such questions from non-homework questions?  If a student relied upon such answers, that could lead them to accusations of plagiarism even considering that the answers would be in the public domain, since students are required to submit their own work.

Secondly, where is the objectivity?  Wouldn't the value of the questions and answers come down to a subjective assessment of how interesting they are to the user reading them?  People's tastes differ, and users who wouldn't usually read or like a story of a particular genre may still read and vote on a question or answer of that genre, and hence skew the voting score.  If enough users did this, it might become simply a matter of how many users like or dislike the particular genre.

Finally, I don't believe that the art of story-telling should be reduced to running to a Q&A site whenever the writer gets stuck for ideas.  I use WB SE to get answers to questions on topics that I'm not an expert on, but my stories' plots are entirely my own.  If I relied on a StoryBuilding SE, I don't think that they would be any more.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, how are we able to avoid anything you mention in your first paragraph? We answer storybuilding questions all the time. We've answered the question of copyright twice that I know of in Meta and twice over at [law.se], and there's no copyright protection due to SE's use of CC-BY-SA. Next, I'm not sure objectivity is an overriding requirement by SE anymore. Where's the objectivity in 30% of the questions we answer here? Finally, I suspect every author on Earth with writer's block would disagree with paragraph #3. (Pros wouldn't ask here anyway.)

Comment: We shouldn't be answering storybuilding questions. Ideally they should be closed before a single answer is posted, instead of having people argue that it's permissible to ask whatever you want on this site without restriction.

Comment: To be fair, the art of geopoesy (worldbuilding) can't be reduced to a mere Q&A session either. That doesn't mean Q&A isn't valuable.

Comment: "*Secondly, where is the objectivity? Wouldn't it come down to a subjective assessment of how interesting they are to the user reading them? [...] and hence skew the voting score*": Both statements are already happening : Everyone always judge something with their own point-of-view, and vote scores are already skewed by which answer/vote/comment comes first. As much as this goes against the official saying, stack-exchange being objective through their score is false just because of how people are affected by their biases :).

Answer (score 3):

#### The MIDDLE WAY

**Problems:**
I too like questions about story building. Good ones anyway! I believe Monty has a valid point as far as objectivity goes. While writing and storycraft do have rules and conventions and loads of 'wisdom of the ages' that can help craft a good story, I agree that there are loads of ways to craft a good story! Objectivity would be possible on SB.SE, but still far from Stack Exchange's ideal. They suffer our existence, but if they caught wind of us being behind the creation of yet another almost entirely subjective, entirely opinion based forum, I think they'd nix it.

Monty also mentions plagiarism. In my opinion, I'm not convinced that it would be a huge issue. No worse, anyway, than what might occur here in WB. It's still a valid consideration, and since I daresay SB.SE would largely be owned and operated by us, it just means we'd have two forums in which to herd cats.

VLAZ makes a good point about SB.SE becoming a clearing house for writing prompts. This would be a far worse problem than subjectivity.

**Solution:**
I agree with JBH that one could construe a lack of storybuilding resources on Stack Exchange, and thus such a forum might be seen as useful. However, I don't think its utility counts for enough to make a whole new forum.

If WB's question load were 50% story related questions, then perhaps it would make sense to create the forum. Story questions, while frequent, just aren't that common. So for me, a new forum would be a somewhat squishy no.

However, there is a way we can have our cake and eat it too, and that is quite simple. We, the undersigned, the VTC Brigade, the people whose voices are most likely to be heard here in Meta, the people who are regularly the most active in Main, simply have to **relax our hardline stance on GOOD storybuilding questions**.

We could very easily have a conversation about what constitutes "good storybuilding queries" and what constitutes trash. If we can come up with a small number of good question categories, we could simply look the other way when such queries appear.

I've been doing exactly this for years when it comes to "opinion based" questions, and I am more than amenable to do the same for good story based questions!

I think I'll give that a try!

Comment: I have no fundamental argument with what you're asking - other than without a policy statement people can point to for confirmation, it's a complete waste of time. I took a rough crack at it with my attempt to get brainstorming properly codified and, from my perspective, ended up villified. I'd be delighted if you or someone else wants to take a shot at it. I'd happily support it. But without that stated policy (which almost necessitates a change in the Too Story-Based VTC reason and supporting policy), I'm out.

Comment: And by "relax our hardline stance" we mean "return to the stance exactly as it existed roughly 2 years ago, as ample evidence documents". I can find no relevant rule changes that explain why the stance has changed over the last 2 years, or what problem the VTC brigade really feels they are saving us from with their diligent work. 2 years ago there were still plenty of questions to close. Even the anti-VTC brigade agrees that some things are clearly out of scope. But the site sure seemed a lot more useful (and fun) back then. Also incidentally where the VTC brigade got most of their rep.

Comment: @JBH --- therein lies the problem. Policy change is unlikely to happen. Especially since it's been drummed into everyone's heads that no story based queries are on topic. A viable new forum is unlikely to happen since it's founding principles are almost as bad as ours. *shrugs* None of us really need a policy to turn a blind eye towards a good story question, is all I'm saying!

Comment: @JamieB --- could be! As for stance change, I think those come and go. WB has gotten a lot more realism trumps all, and has certainly cracked down on story based questions. Mind you, a lot of story queries ought to be off topic here. I'm not worried about those as they should be closed on sight. Some, though, pose interesting narrative conundrums that fuse world system with action of character; others are highly imaginative and creative: those I'm much less inclined to VTC.

Comment: @JamieB Boy, you're full of it. What this site was like *five years ago* before any of the rule and policy changes (including the Real World Question policy) was amazing. If you think just two years ago was substantially different from today then you're only looking at questions that fit your view. I have no respect for newbies that glom onto other people's tag lines and pretend to know anything at all about the history they've walked in on. And if you look at my activity profile page, you'll see that 60% of my rep came before 2021. You, on the other hand, earned all of 41 rep before 2021.

Comment: @JBH --- I'm glad you pay attention to the history of this place! I can't keep up with it, but I always know that when you as a Meta question or write an answer, it's going to be an education in and of itself!

Comment: @jbh Fortunately I can ignore your opinion as easily as you can ignore mine. What's really funny is when the moderator answers a question and then the VTC cabal votes it closed -- essentially you're saying the moderator was wrong to answer. Clearly some of you have gotten way off the page with the rest of the community, and at some point you'll need to step back and re-evaluate.

Comment: @JamieB --- All that really demonstrates is people have different ideas on what should be closed and what should remain open. The mod wasn't necessarily "wrong" to answer; however, it might be a more prudential action to refrain from answering if a question is in the close queue with four VTC. That's generally indicative that there is some kind of problem.

Comment: @elemtilas I disagree with the reasoning that 4 close votes is a stop sign-- it's also why "vote to reopen" exists. Even if a question is fully closed, you only need 5 people who disagree with that decision and it can be reopened (no editing of the question required!). Unfortunately, closed questions sink rapidly off the active page so it's harder to get eyes on and reopen than it is to close. But jbh has convinced me that rep is the true measurement of authority, which is why I hope newbies like him and I can stand united behind the true authority of veterans like willk, who had a great idea!

Comment: @JamieB --- I didn't say stop sign. It's more a "look to your left because there's an articulated juggernaut coming your way" sign. If you disagree and think the question is fine, by all means state your objection and answer it! And I agree 100%, VTR if you think it's warranted!

Comment: Yeah, I do agree "factors need to be looked at" before answering, but I also wish the VTC cabal would do the same. When I go through the VTC queue, I look at the question but I also look at how many upvotes it has had, whether it has any good answers already, etc. VTC on a popular question with many upvotes and some good answers is swimming against the stream and going against the community. Of course, the community can still be wrong but the VTC cabal isn't helping their case when they yank the rug out from under the community.

Comment: @JamieB --- Same. With the caveat that just because everyone *likes* a question really doesn't mean that it's a good or appropriate question. I take that into account too. I end up not VTC many questions and often end up defending questions in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.  Good idea!**

And no need to go to Area 51.  This new stack will be the old stack called Worldbuilding Stack.  Worldbuilding Stack will let down its hair and open its arms.  The emphasis on black and white may continue on other stack sites but WB will be black, white, shades of gray and also the color of that dress that is gold and also blue.  Also there may be UV colors that only cell phones can see.   The old will be good.  The new will now also be good!  Votes to close will be reserved for the brutally terse, unanswerably broad or the plain incomprehensible.  On the new WB stack the good the bad and the ugly will link arms and do high kicks, Rockette style!  It will be the WB Stack that WB Stack strives to be!  Has striven to be?  Strove?  A little help with that please.

In any case, persons who find their undies in a bundle about the agape love newly to be found on WB Stack thanks to JBH will be invited to update their wardrobe for the new age or relocate to the Mathematics stack.

Answer (score 1):

**A Response from Stack Exchange Staff**

While deciding whether or not to continue advocating for this idea, I decided to ask the opinion of SE staff. Here's what I wrote:

> 30 Jan 2023
>
> In reference to [Should we try to create Storybuilding.SE?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10055/40609). I am the user who posted the question.
>
> It's probably time that we officially heard from a Stack Exchange employee concerning the viability of petitioning at Area 51 a sister site to Worldbuilding: Storybuilding. It appears that an increasing number of subjective sites are appearing (e.g., Academia, Code Review, Community Building, Expatriates, Freelancing, Interpersonal Skills, Workplace, and others) wherein answers are less objective and more opinion-based. Answers are based on experience, wisdom, and even creativity vs. qualitative and quantitative best practices. And querents are asking questions that are almost always relevant only to themselves and their project/issue (i.e., the question almost never serves to help a significant number of people in the future).
>
> Why am I asking? Because story-based (storybuilding) questions are by far and away the most popular questions on Worldbuilding. People who try to police the rules (yes, like me) are unpopular because people don't want interference with what they're doing.
>
> And, as fate would have it, what they're doing is writing stories more often than strictly building worlds.
>
> Thus, I ask if Stack Exchange today would arbitrarily prohibit a pitch for storybuilding simply because it still sees itself (as it did a decade ago) as a strictly objective site expecting questions that lead to answers that can help a potentially large group of people? I'm neither for nor against, but if SE's goals still preclude a Stack as subjective as Storybuilding would be, then I can report that and discontinue the meta discussion. But, if you're willing to hear the proverbial pitch and believe SE can embrace that level of subjectivity, then I'll continue to seek support.

Here is SE's response:

> Hey JBH,
>
> I'm Slate, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. In general, we're willing to help see sites through the Area 51 process as best we can. There's no strict requirement for sites to have singular objective answers; however, questions need to be answerable in such a way that answers can be meaningfully weighed in comparison to each other on their merits. For example, I strongly suspect such a site could not reasonably be a place for writing prompts, where the answers respond to the writing prompt. Similarly, questions need to be able to be weighed according to quality standards that the site sets out, and I foresee some potential challenges for a Storybuilding site in defining what a good question can or should look like.
>
> ***However, I do need to caution that, with the existence of Worldbuilding, Writers, Freelancing, and Literature, the topic of story development is already quite thoroughly covered by existing ground.*** If you do want to initiate such a proposal, I would strongly encourage you to take good care to differentiate its scope clearly from the existing sites on the network.
>
> At the end of the day, we gauge each Area 51 proposal on its own merits, both in terms of the quality of content it's likely to produce, and how clearly it differentiates its use case from other sites on the network. To a certain extent, I suspect we won't be able to give you a definitive answer as to whether Storybuilding could succeed until we have a concrete proposal to evaluate. Please let me know if you've got any questions I can help with.
>
> Thanks,
> Slate

The bold statement says that between four Stacks ([Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/), and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)) the ability to ask storybuilding questions exists. I disagree:

- Worldbuilding states in its Help Center, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." Storybuilding is not allowed.
- While Writing states in its Help Center that questions about fiction are on-topic, "Questions asking what to write about." are off-topic. They continue, "We're looking to avoid questions where the intent is to generate ideas." Storybuilding is not allowed.
- Literature states in its help center that "Questions about creating literature yourself" are off-topic. Storybuilding is not allowed.
- The outlier is Freelancing. I've asked on that Stack if they'd accept storybuilding questions. I doubt they will. Their Help Center doesn't specifically exclude storybuilding, but everything about what they do accept is focused on the *profession of freelancing,* not what to write as a freelancer. Their Tour has an example question that's 100% storybuilding, but the tour concludes by excluding opinion-based questions (which might be a Stack Exchange template requirement). I'll update this post with their response.

In conclusion, I disagree with Stack Exchange's staff that storybuilding is already accommodated somewhere on Stack Exchange — unless you assume that our regularly-ignored rules against storybuilding questions constitutes a solution.

Comment: I think  you are reading it wrong: the bold sentence simply states that, among those 4 communities, there is already SOME storybuilding covered. It doesn't say that WB covers Storybuilding.

Comment: @L.Dutch Updated.

Comment: almost there: "with the existence of Worldbuilding, Writers, Freelancing, and Literature, the topic of story development is already *quite thoroughly* covered [...] take good care to differentiate its scope clearly from the existing sites on the network". I read it as "if storybuilding was a pie, those 4 take 80% of it, so be careful to properly define that 20% to stand out

Comment: @L.Dutch I'd take that intepretation is you believe there's 20% to work with. It seems to me that there's 100% to work with. I've not yet heard back from Freelancing, but I'll be shocked if they say they accept storybuilding questions.